# user validation and activation code for web and app

Tags: python, django

I am working on a system where user can register from either web or mobile app using API.

When registering from web I am sending user validation url with hashed key in the url. When user clicks the url it will check for the user and activate the user. I am using user's email on activation code so it will be unique for every user. This is for web flow. (If any better approach I would love to hear)

For api I am thinking to ask for platform. If it is web same process will follow if it is for mobile then I am thinking to send some activation code in the email. Activation code might be of 4 or 8 digit.

I am confused here is should I randomly generate these code or the code should be associated with something like email or phone no ?

Comment: If the code is derived from email or phone and someone really want to spam your site (or worse- pretend to be someone else), he could create few genuine accounts and figure out how you create the activation code from mail/phone, and then he could register with whoever he like and just create the activation code himself and pretend to own that number/email account. so I wouldn't suggest making the code base on email/phone.

Comment: @Ness What would be the best practice ??

Comment: Why not go the same way that you are using in web? Let the user click on the link and you redirect it to your app (possible in android through deep linking) to that particular page in your app. All you have to do is check for the user-agent in your API request header and make the redirection accordingly.

Comment: Also, if you want to create a code, a random code is your best chance to go about it.